# Need help regex matching a buffer name and switching to it

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, tramp, projectile

I write code on one system (x86) and ssh into another (ARM) to compile my code. I use tramp to ssh from within emacs. Projectile command (projectile-project-root) give this info:

```
/home/userX/projectY
```

The buffer name after sshing into remote system and be under same project is:

```
/ssh:userX@sxy-ss-02:/home/userX/projectY
```

What is a lisp code that would:

1. Figure out the project name after calling (projectile-project-root)
2. Matching on the buffer that has the remote login and ends with project name
3. switch to that buffer.

Basically, matching (from the list of opened buffer) on /ssh:....../projectY

Comment: That `/ssh:...` string is what you use to open the remote directory but are you sure that's the name of the buffer? IME, unless you have explicitly renamed it, the name of the buffer would be `projectY`.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your comment. It does actually name the buffer the full /ssh:servername:directory

Comment: I spoke too soon, I believe you are correct. If the same directory is open in tramp and locally then I would see two buffers projx<> and projx</ssh:userx@serverx:>. If the directory is only open in tramp then it's buffer will be simply named the projx name. Do you have a suggestion on how I can achieve what I want? Is there an option in tramp to always force full name with the /ssh part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested - add this to your init file:

```
 (setq remote-user "userX")
 (setq remote-host "sxy-ss-02")

 (defun switch-buffer-to-remote-project ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((tramp-name (format "/ssh:%s@%s:%s" remote-user remote-host (projectile-project-root))))
      (find-file tramp-name)))

 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-Z") #'switch-buffer-to-remote-project)
```

It binds the command to `C-c C-z` which was undefined in my case, but you might want to choose a different keybinding for it.

Comment: becs i posted this question on multiple forums and got no response for a while. much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help!